# Наполнения списка случайными числами с последующей сортировкой

Tags: python, сортировка, случайные-числа

Как создать список в *Python*. После этого хочу заполнить этот список случайными числами, как положительными, так и отрицательными, а далее отсортировать (по убыванию или возрастанию).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/qQtxSK

```
import random

a = [random.randint(-100, 100) for x in range(random.randint(0, 100))]
print(a)

a.sort()
print(a)
```