# Как можно доделать код?

Tags: python

```
import random

a = [random.randint(-100, 100) for x in range(random.randint(0, 100))]
```

помогите доделать пожалуйста доделать код.

Приняв положительные значения за радиусы окружностей, вычислить
соответствующие длины окружностей

Comment: Эм.. А ты вообще программировать умеешь, или будешь по строчке кода собирать из разных вопросов без изменений? Источник кода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987034/178988

Comment: Когда кто-то просит сделать задание *за него*, я минусую такие вопросы из чувства солидарности к тем, кто во время семестра учится, а не бездельничает, надеясь на халяву. Отвечать на такое - значит поощрять такое безответственное поведение.

Comment: Бро, те кто во время семестра учится от этого ничего не теряют) наоборот вырастут квалифицированные программисты , не сказать что я прям не учусь, да мне легче понять тему на готовом примере (к сожалению препод такой возможности не предостовляет) но это не значит что я не хочу чему нибудь научиться или как то задеваю права более смышленых программистов)Если своим поведением я задел твои чувства ,то прости.

Comment: И большой спасибо тем кто помогает , ребята вы лучшие.

Comment: @trollingchar, на мой взгляд, неправильный подход. Простые вопросы тоже полезны. Я вот например питон не знаю, но некий интерес к нему есть, иногда отвечаю на какие-то вопросы. При этом, я сам всякую мелочь гуглю - вплоть до "python sqrt" - и такие вопросы есть на английском SO и с огромным числом плюсов, потому что есть куча людей и куча причин, которым эта информация поможет. Вопрос "как сгенерировать случайный список" полезен - такой вопрос будут искать в гугле и найдут как раз тут. Его не надо минусовать и закрывать. И про вычисление квадратного корня - тоже не надо.

Comment: @trollingchar, а вот вопрос-задачка из учебника, например, "напишите программу, которая считывает массив, умножает все элементы на 4 и выводит его" - бессмысленен. Никто не будет гуглить такой вопрос. Но по отдельность вопросы о считывании и выводе массива хорошие. Да и о преобразовании тоже. Т. е. для элементарных вопросов стоит подходить по принципу "может ли мне (или кому-то ещё) понадобиться гуглить такое" - если ответ "да", то вопрос хороший. Кстати, хотелось бы комплект вопросов про echo-программу на разных языках. PS: Надо было на мете писать, а не в комментариях - даже не лезет...

Comment: @Qwertiy я не буду спорить, ибо у каждого из нас свое мнение. Я даже соглашусь с тем, что простые вопросы тоже стоит задавать. Просто для меня есть разница между вопросом "объясните как работает цикл" и "напишите мне задачу на циклы". В первом случае видно стремление получить знания, и тогда я помогаю их получить.

Comment: @Travolta98 если бы ты стремился чему-нибудь научиться как ты говоришь, ты бы легко нагуглил как это сделать. Скорее всего ты даже не понимаешь суть того, что от тебя требуется в задании. А иначе в чем проблема?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import random

a = [random.randint(-100, 100) for x in range(random.randint(0, 100))]

def recursive_len(some_list):
    if not some_list:
        return 0
    len_circle = (3.14 * 2) * some_list[-1]
    print("r={:2}, len_circle={:7.2f}".format(some_list[-1], len_circle))
    return 1 + recursive_len(some_list[:-1])

recursive_len([ i for i in a if i>0 ])

r=19, len_circle= 119.32
r=63, len_circle= 395.64
r=25, len_circle= 157.00
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Qwertiy за объяснение.
Возможно это поможет:

```py
import random
from math import pi


li = [random.randint(-100, 100) for x in range(random.randint(0, 100))]
res = [2*pi*x for x in li if x > 0]

print(res)
```

Comment: Он имеет в виду выбрать `x > 0` из того списка, а потом уже `map` на длины окружностей.

Comment: @Qwertiy так тут в коде вроде бы это и сделано? Что не так?

Comment: Я правил код, раньше было не так.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, я вот [на эту версию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/987052/2) отвечал. Убрал неактуальный комментарий.

Comment: @nomnoms12, когда отвечаешь в комментариях без `@`, уведомление приходит только автору сообщения и единственному кроме тебя оставлявшему под ним комментарии. В данном случае комментарии были от двух людей, и сообщение тоже твоё, т. е. уведомление не получил вообще никто.